# E: unable to crorrect problems, apt-get install nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Trying to install npm on Elementary OS but it gives me the following error, any suggestion on how to resolve this???

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed

    Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install npm`
3. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

However, You may not be able to install the latest version of nodejs via apt and also, it will be hard, if you want to switch between the node versions.

I would recommend, using `NVM`(Node Version Manager)

Installing node using NVM:

1. `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.1/install.sh | bash`
2. `source ~/.bashrc`
3. `nvm install <node-version-you-want-to-install>`

For more information on NVM, see: https://github.com/creationix/nvm